# firefox crash Bus error (core dumped)

Tags: firefox

I am quite sure it has to do with the last security update I have installed (today 9 Apr 2014). 
I have ubuntu 13.10.

Firefox crashes after 5 seconds I launch the application. It doesn't matter what I do, after some time it crashes.

That's what I get from the console:

```
$firefox -safe-mode

(process:9908): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:9908): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:9908): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:9908): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:9908): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property    GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I moved the .mozilla/firefox folder, I even reinstalled, but the beheaviour is the same.(Kind of breaks right after receiving the request from the server, but sometimes I can see google for a couple of seconds before it breaks)

What should I do to have firefox running again? Or is firefox over for me? :(

(Btw, it wasn't immadiate, maybe because I had the browsers open when I accept the security update that I think is the guilty of everything, but it asks me to update adobe flash plugin to watch youtube -even though I have no problem at watching videos- , when there is no package like that in the ubuntu software center)

Comment: The messages starting with (firefox:<pid>) are perfectly normal, in fact I get exactly those when starting from the terminal. The Bus error is more serious. I suppose you should report these as a bug to Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is the solution. But I got this working (presumably lasts).

Following my theory that everything was caused by the security update and that the "update flash plugin" was related to it I came to do the following:

-Youtube finally stop working and I desperately needed some music to work. I tried to download the plugin but I couldn't so I visited this page:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1902832

i did this:
Simply activate it by going to System Settings>Software Sources>Other Software and check the boxes for Canonical Partners.

Then I was able to find the flash plugin and I installed it.

Everything is working now, firefox, youtube, I hope even prezi works.

I sincerely hope this helps somebody else.