# Firefox, "Bus error (core dumped)"

Tags: apt, firefox, flash

If I try to launch firefox I get:

> Bus error (core dumped)

When, until last week, I had Gnome 12.04 it was the same... then, during the upgrade (I now have 14.04) Firefox started working (without Flash Player). I installed Flash Player and Firefox stopped working.

Since I am no expert at all, in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445307/firefox-crash-bus-error-core-dumped) I honestly don't understand what does *"Simply activate it by going to System Settings>Software Sources>Other Software and **check the boxes for Canonical Partners**"* mean (I have the box for Canonical Patners checked, if that is).

I tried the following things found on the Web:

- If `firefox -safe-mode` it's the same
- Tried `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all firefox` , then `sudo apt-get install firefox` , nothing.
- Disinstalled Flash Player, useless
- Like [suggested here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-103930.html), `rm -r ~/.mozilla` . Too bad for me.
- [Then nothing](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162972) removing `~/.config/dconf/user`, whatever

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which happened after an update of the flash plugin.  To fix it, I disabled the flash plugin by:

```
~$ mv ~/.macromedia{,~}
```

which moves away the entire `~./macromedia` directory, thus rendering it invisible for Firefox.  Something in there crashed Firefox.

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: @Barat It worked for me.  Your problem must be caused by something else.  You could try uninstalling/disabling (system-wide) plugins.